# What burnt through my WD Black SN750?

Tags: ssd

I installed a brand new 500GB WD Black SN750 NVMe SSD in my i7-6700K 32GB RAM PC 3.5 years ago.

The drive has always been <60% full and also has 16GB unallocated space left on it from day 1.

I use the machine mainly for Excel and browser based work.

Out of curiosity I looked at its health to find it's showing a TBW value of 375TB!

The specs rate the endurance at 300TBW.

I suspect it might be the browser caches - I use both Firefox and Chrome very very heavily (like over a dozen windows with 20 tabs each - I know it's crazy and it's a habit I'm trying to break, but it's hard ok? don't have a go!).

I'm wondering if there's a way to log which programs are writing to the C: drive in total over a period - say a day or week to find out which are the worst culprits?

I know I can get point in time values from Resource Monitor, but would rather use something that can monitor/report for me while I work normally.

I've heard of Windows Performance Counters, but have never used them and wouldn't know where to start or even if they would be suitable for the task.

I also just realised I had originally turned hibernate off but had turned it back on when the PV guys wanted to turn the mains off half way through my working day and I forgot to turn it off again - so perhaps the hibernate file has been burning through my SSD endurance too as I normally put the machine to sleep at the end of the day and simply resume it in the morning.

I've turned hibernate off again now. I spoke to WD Support today and the guy said the drive will probably be ok up to around 500TBW but obviously maintain backups and corruption free operation can't be expected once the rated endurance rating has been exceeded.

I'm going to replace the drive real soon as I can't afford to have it flake out on me half way through a workday, but want to optimise the new drive set-up so it lasts longer than this one did.

Comment: Probably something you need to analyse and find. I have a Samsung 1 TB on one laptop 20 months old, 4 machines running simultaneously, 3 are shrunk and re-written weekly. Machines run 24x7.  Endurance is 600TBW.  So far I am at 30 TBW. I have another laptop Samsung 1 TB 6 years old and did the 4 machines 24 x 7 for 4 years. So far about 60 TBW. So I would say some activity of yours.

Comment: I have a Lenovo Desktop purchased at the same time as the first laptop above. No virtual machines. Otherwise it runs 24x7.  <10 TBW so far.

Comment: I have a thousand of browsers tabs open at any point, I seriously doubt, it’s your browser at fault nor is your hibernation at fault.

Comment: 300 TBW is a hell of a lot - don't worry about it.

Comment: Windows update might have caused some of it: https://www.extremetech.com/computing/314335-fix-for-potential-ssd-damaging-bug-coming-in-windows-update?source=Computing

Comment: OK, this is doing my head in now. The new WD Black SN850X 1TB has been in for 19 days and it's showing 4TBW written already!

Comment: I even installed an Intel Optane 16GB I had lying round and repointed the Firefox and Chrome cache's to it. 

Just looking into this: https://www.servethehome.com/firefox-is-eating-your-ssd-here-is-how-to-fix-it/
It looks like it might be Firefox chewing through my SSD